# Closest Pairs by sweeping vertically

Tags: c++, algorithm, computational-geometry

The standard sweep line algorithm for closest pairs is well known, as described [here](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lineSweep), which uses a sweep line to sweep horizontally across the set of points, maintaining only those within the current best distance of the current point.

Normally, the points must initially be sorted by x-coordinate, and the bounding box (std::set in the case of a c++ implementation) must be sorted by y-coordinate, as can be seen in [this c++ implementation](http://olympiad.cs.uct.ac.za/presentations/camp1_2009/linesweep_handout.pdf).

However, when trying to implementing I accidentally forgot to sort the points by x-coordinate and instead sorted them by y-coordinate. Surprisingly, this still seemed to work. 
You can see my implementation [here](http://ideone.com/Gate9h), which essentially follows a slightly modified version of the standard linesweep closest pairs algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#define x second
#define y first

typedef pair<long long, long long> pll;

inline double dist(pll p1, pll p2)
{
    return sqrt((double) (p2.y - p1.y)*(p2.y - p1.y) + (p2.x - p1.x)*(p2.x - p1.x));
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int numPoints;
    cin >> numPoints;

    vector <pll> points;
    points.resize(numPoints);

    for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
    {
        cin >> points[i].x >> points[i].y;
    }

    //Sorts the points by y coordinate (because y is first)
    sort(points.begin(), points.end());

    double shortestDistSoFar = INFINITY;
    set <pll> boundingBox; //Bounding box maintained by y-coordinate
    boundingBox.insert(points[0]);

    int left = 0;

    pll best1, best2;

    for (int i = 1; i < numPoints; i++)
    {
        //Maintain only points to the left of the current point whose distance is less than bestDist
        while ((left < i) && (points[i].x - points[left].x > shortestDistSoFar))
        {
            boundingBox.erase(points[left]);
            left++;
        }

        //Consider only points within bestDist of the current point
        for (auto it = boundingBox.lower_bound(pll(points[i].y - shortestDistSoFar, points[i].x - shortestDistSoFar));
             it != boundingBox.end() && it->y <= points[i].y + shortestDistSoFar; it++)
        {
            if (dist(*it, points[i]) < shortestDistSoFar)
            {
                shortestDistSoFar = dist(*it, points[i]);
                best1 = *it;
                best2 = points[i];
            }
        }

        boundingBox.insert(points[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Visit each point in order of increasing y-coordinate and for each point check all points from y-bestDist to y+bestDist, updating bestDist when a new shortest distance is found and removing points from the set whose x-coordinate distance from the current point is greater than bestDist.

Does this modified algorithm still work (I only tested for a few cases), and is the running time still O(N lgN)?

Comment: Remove sqrt from your distance function, it's unnecessary and expensive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does work correctly(because the points are deleted from the set only when they can be safely deleted). However, it has `O(n ^ 2)` time complexity, because the points are not always deleted when they should be.

This simple generator(written in python3):

```
from sys import argv

n = int(argv[1])
dy = 1
dx = -n
print(n)
for i in range(n):
  print(dx * i, dy * i)
```

creates a test case that makes your code perform `O(n ^ 2)` operations for any `n`.

The idea of this test case is very simple: if the points (after sorting by y coordinate) are iterated in a decreasing order of x-coordinate, they are never removed from the set. So if they are located close to each other by y coordinate and far by x coordinate, the entire set is traversed every time. That's why all pairs of points are checked(and there are exactly `n * (n - 1) / 2` pairs).

Now let's see how it works in practice:
Firstly, I compiled your code with `g++ -std=c++11 -O2 closest_pair.cpp`.
After that I ran a bunch of tests:

```
temp$ python3 gen.py 10000 > input
temp$ time ./a.out < input

real    0m0.805s
user    0m0.797s
sys     0m0.008s

temp$ python3 gen.py 30000 > input
temp$ time ./a.out < input

real    0m7.195s
user    0m7.198s
sys     0m0.004s

temp$ python3 gen.py 50000 > input
temp$ time ./a.out < input

real    0m23.711s
user    0m23.725s
sys     0m0.004s
```

As you can see, it works really slowly.